# Creating integer array of resource IDs

Tags: android, arrays, android-resources

I have some images in my `res/drawable` folder. Let's say `img1.png`,
`img2.png` and `img3.png`. I am currently creating an integer array of these image IDs in Java like this

```
int[] imgIds = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};
```

Instead, is it possible to create an integer array in one of `res/values` files (say `strings.xml`) like this

```
<integer-array name="img_id_arr">
    <item>@drawable/img1</item>
    <item>@drawable/img2</item>
    <item>@drawable/img3</item>
</integer-array>
```

and then access it in Java via `getResources().getIntArray(R.array.img_id_arr)`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use just "array" instead of "integer-array". See [Typed Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) in the developer guide.

Comment: This seems to work for drawables but not for styles for example:
    <array name="themes">
      <item>@android:style/Theme</item>
      <item>@android:style/Theme.Light</item>
      <item>@android:style/Theme.Holo</item>
      <item>@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light</item>
    </array>

How can this work for other resource ids aside from drawables?

Comment: I think, as far as i know, is create an int array representing the pre-compiled value itself and not the value what it represents. if someone has any idea it's welcome.

Answer (score 53):

See [XML integer array, resource references, getIntArray](http://www.anddev.org/xml_integer_array_resource_references_getintarray-t9268.html)

```
TypedArray ar = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_array);
int len = ar.length();
int[] resIds = new int[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    resIds[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);
ar.recycle();
// Do stuff with resolved reference array, resIds[]...
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    Log.v (TAG, "Res Id " + i + " is " + Integer.toHexString(resIds[i]));
```

Comment: is it possible to obtain a single reference to a resource instead of an array? i need it in case i want to check if 2 resource ids are equal.

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 2):

Make a [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList). Although it is not exactly what you want, but pretty much achievable.

Comment: Very elegant and very underrated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to keep them in code.

```
private static final int[] AVATARS = new int[]{
            R.drawable.ava_1, R.drawable.ava_2, R.drawable.ava_3...};
```