# Get Android Material Design Color Randomly

Tags: android, material-design, android-resources

I find [this](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/b0b8cfa773488e138037) list of material design color and I want to get random color from it. I am new in android development and don't fully understand how android resources works.

I know that I can get the custom color by `R.color.my_color` from `res/values/colors.xml` but I want to separate my app custom colors from material design colors.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Import the xml file from the link to my project under `res` folder (ex. `res/values/android_material_design_colours.xml`)
2. Get all colors from the file

   `int[] allColors =` (*missing part*)
3. Get the random color by using `Random` class

   `int randomColor = allColors[new Random().nextInt(allColors.length)];`

Is this possible or are there any better way? Please Help.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347107/creating-integer-array-of-resource-ids Instead of drawable use color. I hope everything will be clear. The idea is just the same

Comment: Is this the last way? I mean, I'm looking for a simple way that I don't have to alter the file and not to copy and paste one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I'm avoiding to alter the file, I do it by reading the xml. Good thing Android has class `android.content.res.XmlResourceParser` that simplify xml parsing. I end up with this solution:

Imported the xml [**file**](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/b0b8cfa773488e138037) to my project under `res/xml` folder (ex. `res/xml/android_material_design_colours.xml`)

```
List<Integer> allColors = getAllMaterialColors();
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(allColors.size());
int randomColor = allColors.get(randomIndex);
```

and

```
private List<Integer> getAllMaterialColors() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    XmlResourceParser xrp = getContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.materialcolor);
    List<Integer> allColors = new ArrayList<>();
    int nextEvent;
    while ((nextEvent = xrp.next()) != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String s = xrp.getName();
        if ("color".equals(s)) {
            String color = xrp.nextText();
            allColors.add(Color.parseColor(color));
        }
    }
    return allColors;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create string-array with all material colors.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colors">        
        <item>#ff0000</item>
        <item>#00ff00</item>  
        <item>#0000ff</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Get colors array in the activity

```
String[] allColors = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
```

Parse string value to get int value:

```
int randomColor = Color.parseColor(allColors[new Random().nextInt(allColors.length)]);
```